# How to control memory leaks and nodes on Angular 6

Tags: typescript, service, memory-leaks, angular6, nodes

I'm trying to do it on the rigth way but i'm not able to reduce memory consumtion and nodes created.

The code is like this

```
this.ubService.getList()
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy))
  .subscribe(list => {
    if (list === null) {
      this.showMsg(environment.error_getList);
    } else {
      this.lista = null;
      this.lista = list;
      list = null;
    }
  });
```

On the image above you can see the creation of a lot of nodes after finishing the call.

[Nodes created after finishing  get list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6TMq.png)

How can i reduce it? I can see that memory JS goes down but not the nodes ones.

**UPDATE**:
the code of the table

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of list">
        <td *ngFor="let cell of row; trackBy:trackByCelId" >
            <ng-container *ngIf='cell.id !== null'>
                {{cell.id}}{{cell.name}}
            </ng-container>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

ts code

```
trackByCelId(index, cell:Cell) {
    return index;
}
```

I tray it and the performance is more or less the same.

Comment: what are you doing with this.list? rendering? what's the expected behavior?

Comment: I render this.lista into a table and this table is autoupdating every 2 seconds. So the memory and nodes are always growing up :/

Comment: so you want to replace the existing nodes with the ones you receive every 2 seconds. Try using trackBy in you *ngFor

Comment: I tried with trackBy but de perfomance still the same.

PD: I updete the answer with the html and ts code

Comment: trackBy for rows as well. Actually I believe it's normal that it goes up a bit. Try watching it for a longer time, at some pointer garbage collector is supposed to clean up unused nodes

Comment: It seems that the nodes and js Heap are reduce. Thanks for help :)